# Why is __new__() asking for 4 arguments when initializing an object from a class derived from an abstract base class that wants one argument?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, inheritance, abstract-class

I am using Python 2.7 (using 3 in my case is not possible). I have a base class with some implemented methods and some abstract methods. I am using abc to implement the abstract base class, and the class inherits from ABCMeta, as recommended in some Python2.7 documentation.

```
import rospy
from bayesian.bbn import *
from cr_project.srv import ObservePatch, ObservePatchResponse, ConsumeFlower, ConsumeFlowerResponse
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
import numpy as np


# Base class
class Bee(ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.collected_nectar = 0
        self.bbn = build_bbn(
            self.f_C, self.f_B, self.f_N,
            domains = {
                'C':[0,1,2]
            })
        rospy.init(self.name)


    # Desirability of a flower based on color
    # 0 = red, 1 = blue, 2 = yelloe
    @abstractmethod
    def f_C(self, C):
        pass

    # Desirability of a flower based on how many bees it has
    @abstractmethod
    def f_B(self, B):
        pass

    # probability of a flower containing nectar
    @abstractmethod
    def f_N(self, C, B, N):
        pass

    def calc_patch_probabilities(self, observation):
        rows = observation.rows
        cols = observation.columns
        result = numpy.array([bbn.query(C=f[0], B=f[1]) for f in zip(observation.colors, observation.bees)])
        return result.reshape(rows,cols).tolist()

    def select_flower(self, prob2d):
        row = 0
        col = 0
        max = 0
        for r in range(0, len(prob2d)):
            for c in range(0, len(prob2d[0])):
                if prob2d[r][c] > max:
                    max = prob2d[r][c]
                    row = r
                    col = c

        return row, col


    def start(self):
        observe_srv = rospy.ServiceProxy('ObservePatch', ObservePatch)
        consume_srv = rospy.ServiceProxy('ConsumeFlower', ConsumeFlower)
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            # Observe the flower patch
            observe_req = ObservePatch() # no request data needed
            observation = observe_srv(observe_req)

            # Get probabilities for all flowers and normalize
            prob2d = self.calc_patch_probabilities(observation)

            # consume flower with highest probability
            row, col = self.select_flower(prob2d)
            consume_req = ConsumeFlower()
            consume_req.row = row
            consume_req.col = col
            consume_rsp = consume_srv(consume_req)
            self.collected_nectar += consume_rsp.nectar_received
            rospy.info('%s consumed %d nectar from flower at [%d, %d] and has collected a total of %d nectar', self.name, rsp.nectar_received, row, col, self.collected_nectar)

            # wait a random number of seconds (maximum of 3)
            rospy.sleep(random.uniform(0,3))
```

I then have a subclass that inherits from the Bee base class, and implements the missing functions. I also want to have the `__init__()` constructor set the name that is passed into the base class. This subclass is in a separate file which also has a main function and is executable.

```
class StupidBee(Bee):
    def __init__(self):
        super(StupidBee, self).__init__('StupidBee')

    def f_C(self, C):
        return 1.0/3.0 # Doesn't care about color

    def f_B(self, B):
        return 1.0 # Doesn't care

    def f_N(self, C, B, N):
        return 1.0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        b = StupidBee()
        b.start()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

However, when I try to run it, I get an error with StupidBee().

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./StupidBee.py", line 27, in <module>
    b = StupidBee()
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)
```

I am completely at a loss on what I'm doing wrong, to be honest. I have not declared `__new__()` anywhere, and I have no idea what arguments it needs. What am I missing?

(Note: the code is still a work-in-progress, was not tested yet, and probably has other mistakes and issues)

EDIT:
Here's a minimal reproducible example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Base(ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = nam

    @abstractmethod
    def abs_method(self):
        pass

    def print_name(self):
        print self.name

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Derived, self).__init__('Derived')

    def abs_method(self):
        print "This is a Derived method"


d = Derived()
d.abs_method()
```

Comment: Can you please create a [mcve]?

Comment: Why you're inheriting from `abc.ABCMeta`? It is a metaclass. You should inherit from `abc.ABC` instead or declare `abc.ABCMeta` as metaclass. Don't mix metaclasses with ordinary classes. I'm not sure whether 2.7 metaclasses were similar enough, but 4 expected arguments are `(cls: metaclass type, name: name of new class, bases: tuple of base classes, class_dict: attributes of new class)` in this case.

Comment: Ah, here's the problem, you are inheriting from ABCMeta: class Bee(ABCMeta)

Comment: You're right! It seems I have misinterpreted some documentation that made me thing this was allowed. Using `__metaclass__ = ABCMeta` in the class seems to have fixed the issue. Please submit that as an answer. My apologies for the hefty code, I wasn't sure where the problem lied so I tried to include everything just in case. I will edit the question with a minimal example

Answer (score 1):

As a few commenters have figured out, you've inherited from the wrong base class. If you inherit from `abc.ABCMeta`, then you're making your own metaclass. If you just want to make an abstract base class, you want to either inherit from `abc.ABC`, or to declare that `abc.ABCMeta` is your class's metaclass.

In Python 2, you'll want:

```
from abc import ABC

class Bee(ABC):
    ...
```

Or:

```
from abc import ABCMeta

class Bee:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    ...
```

In Python 3, the latter would be:

```
from abc import ABCMeta

class Bee(metaclass=ABCMeta):
   ...
```